# kubernetes. Priorities selecting the leader master node

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster with three master nodes acting in active/passive mode. One of them is in a separate location with bigger latency and more prone to have network problems.

I'm looking for being able to set priorities about what master node must be the leader if possible.

Does exist this configuration?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change prioritize of master nodes in election. Here is a current [implementation](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/election/lib/election.go).

If you have a separate location with bigger latency, maybe it will be better to create two clusters and use them in [Federaion](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/)?